# unix commands and scripts KSH shell

Tags: unix, command, ksh, tr

I have a file named `test.dat` which has a unicode character as shown below:

```
Mu?oz Rivera 
35 Mu�oz Rivera Ave., Apt 1001
```

I used the below command to remove the unicode character:

```
tr -Ac '[\007-\015][\040-\176]' '[\000*]' < test.dat > sample.dat ;  mv  sample.dat test.dat
```

The command worked well, but the issue is that my file format was in UFT-8, but after execution of the command, the format got converted to ANSI-1252.

What modification should I make to do in the command shown above to retain the character encoding?

And I could see the data in output file in command line as it was before.
But if I open the processed file(o/p file) by using notepad++ or ultra edit I could see in different format(in ansi instead of uft-8).

Comment: Once you remove any unicode characters, the encoding shouldn't matter. Perhaps it's just that that's the default encoding on your machine?

Comment: As there is no metadata built in the file, Editors usually show information about the encoding based on the data they find. Therefore, changing a character may change the guess in the Editor. To change encoding you could/should use iconv, giving you the control which target enconding is used.

Answer (score 0):

### What is UTF-8?

UTF-8 encodes all valid character code points in Unicode with between one and four single-byte (8-bit) values.

### When I strip non-printable characters under decimal 128 break UTF-8?

Your UTF-8 file uses codes over 128 decimal to encode these character code points:

```
Mu?oz Rivera
35 Mu�oz Rivera Ave., Apt 1001

% tr -Ac '[\007-\015][\040-\176]' '[\000*]'
```

This command remove all non printable and replaces with null bytes. This in effect breaks or invalidates the file. It no longer is a compliant UTF-8 file.

Results of file after running your script:

```
% file *.dat
sample.dat: data
test.dat:   UTF-8 Unicode text
% cat sample.dat
Mu?oz Rivera
35 Muoz Rivera Ave., Apt 1001
```